# How to remove dateT~~ in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wrote code for getting the coming Saturday. So I wrote like this and the result is `2020-03-07T04:00:48.306Z`. I found the dateT~~. I just only need the date. I can use the split method, but I don't wanna use this. is there any other way?

```
function getSaturday(d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    var day = d.getDay(),
        diff = d.getDate()+5 - day + (day == 5 ? 7:1); 
    console.log(diff);
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
  }
```

Comment: actually this function returns a date if you want it in another string format, just format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with substr,

```
function getSaturday(d) {
d = new Date(d);
var day = d.getDay(),
    diff = d.getDate()+5 - day + (day == 5 ? 7:1); 
console.log(diff);
return new Date(d.setDate(diff)).toISOString.substr(0,10);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSaturday` function returns a new `Date` object (which is the Saturday).

The simplest way is to use `split` to get the date string back

```
const d = getSaturday(...)
d.toISOString().split("T")[0]
```

But since you don't want to use split. You may want to use `moment`: a very popular and lightweight JavaScript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

And then you can rewrite your function like this:

```js
function getSaturday(d) {
  return moment(d).day("Saturday").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
}

console.log(getSaturday(new Date()))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSaturday(d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    var day = d.getDay(),
        diff = d.getDate()+5 - day + (day == 5 ? 7:1); 
    console.log(diff);
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

function dateSaturday(d) {
  var ds = [
     d.getFullYear(),
     ((d.getMonth()+1) < 10) ? `0${(d.getMonth()+1)}` : (d.getMonth() +1).toString(),
     (d.getDate() < 10) ? `0${d.getDate()}` : d.getDate().toString()
  ];
  return ds.join("-")
}

console.log(dateSaturday(getSaturday("2020-03-04")));
```

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)